# How to set the correct zoom-factor of vtkCamera?

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I want to increase the size of image equal to 50%,100%, 200%, 400% and 800%. For zooming the DICOM image.for this i will take QComboBox inside my viewer and its index to (50,100,200,400,800).

From the combobox I am getting the index of what percent I need to increase.for
(example- index(0)-50%,index(1)-100%....so on).

I am using "vtk(getActiveCamera())" to increase the size of the image according to the selected index.

I am facing the problem that when I set the size up to 200% it will be set correctly. But when I increase the size to 400% it will be set to 200%+400% =600%. Obviously, I want to set the size only 400%.

Here is my code:

```
    void ViewerManager::vtkZoomCaller(int index)
    {
        int i;
        switch (index)
        {
        case 0:
            //qDebug() << "hello50";
            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfViewers; i++) {
                    viewerDerived[i]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(0.5);
                }
            break;
        case 1:
            //qDebug() << "hello100";
            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfViewers; i++) {
                viewerDerived[i]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(1);

            }
 break;
        case 2:
            //qDebug() << "hello200";
            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfViewers; i++) {
                viewerDerived[i]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(2);
                }

            break;
        case 3:
            //qDebug() << "hello400";
            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfViewers; i++) {
                viewerDerived[i]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(4);
                }
break;
        case 4:
            //qDebug() << "hello800";
            for (i = 0; i < NumberOfViewers; i++) {
                viewerDerived[i]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(8);
                }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

When I want to select 100% after the 200% and above any percent then it will not decrease the size.
Any help is very useful for me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: May I ask you to mark the answer as accepted. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you have shared I see two issues:

- `vtkCamera::Zoom` accepts `double` as an argument.
- That redundancy in the code is not necessary. Actually there is a more elegant way to accomplish that using [QHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html).

Taking this into consideration, I have prepared and example you could try:

```
QHash<int, double> hash;
auto *comboZoom = new QComboBox(this);

hash.insert(0, 0.5);
hash.insert(1, 1.0);
hash.insert(2, 2.0);
hash.insert(3, 4.0);
hash.insert(4, 8.0);

comboZoom->addItems(QStringList{"50%", "100%", "200%", "400%", "800%"});

connect(comboZoom, static_cast<void (QComboBox::*)(int)>(&QComboBox::currentIndexChanged), [hash](int index){
    for (int n = 0; n < numberOfViewers; n++) {
        viewerDerived[n]->GetRenderer()->GetActiveCamera()->Zoom(hash.value(index));
    }
});
```

Comment: @AmarKumar did you try this solution?

Comment: from mainwindow.cpp . I am getting the index and inside the ViewerManager.cpp I am increasing the value( changing the value).